# how to preserve logger settings across project

Tags: python, django, logging, celery

I added a custom logging handler to my django app that writes log entries to a database.

```
class DbLogHandler(logging.Handler): # Inherit from logging.Handler
    def __init__(self):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.entries = []
        logging.debug("*****************[DB] INIT db handler")

    def emit(self, record):
        # instantiate the model
        logging.debug("*****************[DB] called emit on db handler")
        try:
            revision_instance = getattr(record, 'revision', None)
            logEntry = MyModel(name=record.name,
                                  log_level_name=record.levelname,
                                  message = record.msg,
                                  module = record.module,
                                  func_name = record.funcName,
                                  line_no = record.lineno,
                                  exception = record.exc_text,
                                  revision = revision_instance
                                  )
            if revision_instance is None:
                return
            self.entries.append(logEntry)

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        return

    def flush(self):
        if self.entries:
            MyModel.objects.bulk_create(self.entries)
            logging.info("[+] Successfully flushed {0:d} log entries to "
                         "the DB".format(len(self.entries)))
        else:
            logging.info("[*] No log entries for DB logger")
```

I add this handler explicitly to my celery logging like so:

In `my_app.celery_logging.logger`

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

class CeleryAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    """Adapter to add current task context to "extra" log fields."""
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        if not celery.current_task:
            return msg, kwargs

        kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        kwargs.setdefault('extra', {})['celery'] = \
            vars(celery.current_task.request)
        return msg, kwargs

def task_logger(name):
    """
    """
    # first get the default celery task logger
    log = get_task_logger(name)

    # if available, add the db handler explicitly to the celery task
    # logger
    handlers = settings.LOGGING.get('handlers', [])
    if handlers:

        db_handler_dict = handlers.get('db', None)

        db_handler_dict.pop('class', None)
        loglevel = db_handler_dict.pop('level', None)
        db_handler = DbLogHandler()
        if loglevel:
            db_handler.setLevel(loglevel)
        formatter = Formatter(BASIC_FORMAT)
        db_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(db_handler)

    # wrap the logger by the CeleryAdapter to add some celery specific
    # context to the logs
    return CeleryAdapter(log, {})
```

But once out of the scope of `@task` the db-loghandler isn't picked up anymore. How do I establish my logger settings globally?

Comment: Not an answer, but logging to database is a well-known anti-pattern...

Comment: why? can you point me to some references that are discussing your point?

Comment: There are quite a few discussions about this on the net. The two main points are 1. it will fill up your db much quicker than you would expect and 2. it's quite unreliable, specially if you want to log a database access related problem...  If you want to build a log database for other reasons please do it but 1. make it a different db and 2. make sure your logs _first_ go to a more standard log (system, file, whatever) so you won't loose anything if you're db goes down. You may want to discuss this with sysadmins on a sysadmin place FWIW?

Comment: it is supposed to a complementary log so there are also different log files logging info is written to (``django.log``, ``celery-stderr.log``, ``celery-stdout.log`` etc). But thanks for naming the biggest drawbacks.

Comment: @LarsVegas Please show how you call `task_logger`. And explain how you determine that "out of the scope of `@task` the db-loghandler isn't picked up anymore." Edit the question.

Comment: Logging to a transactional relational db isn't wise unless you have a really good reason to do it. It's more efficient to log to files, syslog, and/or a logging service like loggly. Dynamodb isn't terrible for some kinds of logging, and I really like sentry for errors and exceptions.